# ImageMagick: put white background under transparent PNG, then invert colors

Tags: bash, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a PNG image with a black shape on transparent background.
I need a white shape on a solid black background instead.

How can I achieve that with Imagemagick?

Image example:

**I have this:**

[image]

**I want this:**

[image]

Comment: Post your image and expected result.

Answer (score 5):

The image you posted is not transparent. It has an opaque checkerboard background. However, if it was transparent, this Imagemagick command should work.

```
convert image.png -background white -flatten -negate result.png
```

If using Imagemagick 7, then change convert to magick

Answer (score 1):

As @fmw42 said, your image is not a true PNG image. So for your image you can do:

```
convert input.png -white-threshold 0% -negate out.png
```

Which will give you:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Might be able to simply extract the alpha channel to a new image.

For example, let's create a transparent image.

```
 convert -size 100x100 xc:transparent -fill black -draw 'circle 50,50 50,10' transparent.png
```

[image: transparent.png]

Now we can extract the alpha channel knowing that fully transparent is black, and opaque is white.

```
 convert transparent.png -alpha extract output.png
```

[image: output.png]